# System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

There is no longer a static method on the Assembly class in WinRT for gaining access to the current executing assembly? What is the methodology for this in WinRT?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
using System.Reflection;
...
typeof(Class).GetTypeInfo().Assembly
```

where `Class` would normally be the class that you're writing this code in.

Comment: @keithwarren7 It's an extension method that lives in `System.Reflection` namespace (where `TypeInfo` itself is defined), so you need to add that to your usings first. I'll update the answer.

Comment: -1: And how the hell can I use this trick in a framework which sees no class from my Executing Assembly?

Comment: @TDaver The question was on how to get a _current executing_ assembly. If the framework is in its own assembly, then when it's running, _it_ is the current executing assembly. If you need to get a caller's assembly, then that's a different question.

Comment: @PavelMinaev: yes you're right, sorry for my mistake. I was looking for the `Entry` assembly...

Comment: @PavelMinaev Do you have a native solution for TDaver's problem? In case of Portable Class Libraries, without further packages...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if the follow-up question was about the _caller_ assembly or the _entry_ assembly, since both were mentioned, and they don't always coincide. For the entry assembly `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly` is the canonical way to do this, but I don't know if it's available in PCL profile. For the calling assembly, it's `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly` - but it is not reliable in the face of optimizations (think about JIT inlining code across assembly boundaries), so there's simply no good answer to it other than "don't do it".