# How can I get the executing assembly version information in a Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, reflection, windows-8, windows-store-apps

While porting an application to the Windows Store, I noticed the .NETCore Framework does not include:

`System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`

I used this to get the version information for display on the menu screen. Is there a replacement or am I forced to store the information elsewhere for retrieval?

EDIT:

I've also found that I can extract a version number out of `typeof(MyType).AssemblyQualifiedName` but that seems bad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() in WinRT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451703/system-reflection-assembly-getexecutingassembly-in-winrt)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I am using this :

```
public string GetApplicationVersion()
{
  var ver = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id.Version;
  return ver.Major.ToString() + "." + ver.Minor.ToString() + "." + ver.Build.ToString() + "." + ver.Revision.ToString();
}
```

And if you want assembly version you can get it from Version attribute :

```
public string GetAssemblyVersion(Assembly asm)
{
  var attr = CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>(asm);
  if (attr != null)
    return attr.Version;
  else
    return "";
}
```

For example using main App's assembly :

```
Assembly appAsm = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
string assemblyVersion = GetAssemblyVersion(appAsm);
```

Comment: This is based on the package version, which is one way I guess, but my current setup is relying on default values of build/revision in the assemblyinfo file. If I can't find another way, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @N-ate sorry, don't know