# How to write the app version in a textbox

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, textbox, version

I need to write the app version in a Text box, for example "3.0.0.0".
Is there a way to bind it from xaml, like the localization strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a property in your view-model for assembly version and then bind to it.

Reference this [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213906/how-can-i-get-the-executing-assembly-version-information-in-a-windows-store-app):

```
Assembly appAsm = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
string assemblyVersion = GetAssemblyVersion(appAsm);
```